# Name for posets satisfying Zorn's lemma

Tags: terminology, order-theory

Is there a short name for posets (or rather quasi-orders) where every element is above a minimal element? That is, for orders whose reserve satisfies the conclusion of Zorn's lemma? Barring that, a short name for orders who themselves satisfy the conclusion Zorn's lemma would already help.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. To say that the reverse of a poset satisfies [Zorn's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn%27s_lemma) is not equivalent to saying that every element is above a minimal element.

Comment: @LeeMosher Zorn's Lemma gives you that every element is below a maximal one (just apply it to the upper cone of each element). Switch the order around, and you get that every element is above a minimal one.

Comment: That is, indeed, a conclusion to Zorn's Lemma. But it is a very weak conclusion. The full conclusion to Zorn's Lemma is very much stronger than that very weak conclusion. So, it is not clear what you mean by "an order whose reverse satisfies Zorn's Lemma.

Comment: @LeeMosher It is clear what I mean with that, because I explicitly state "every element is above a minimal one". I've edited to clarify that I refer to the conclusion of ZL, not the prerequisite. In particular, I do not require that any chain is bounded below/above a minimal element.

Comment: I believe the term you are after is "well-founded". Every non-empty subset of the set has a minimal (not minimum) element.

Comment: @PaulSinclair No, well-founded is too strong. For example, $1 + \omega^*$ satisfies my property, but is not well-founded.

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand your notation. Is not $1 + \omega^*$ an ordinal, and therefore well-ordered?

Comment: @PaulSinclair $\omega^*$ is $\omega$ with the ordering reversed, so $\ldots < 4 < 3 < 2 < 1 < 0$. In $1 +\omega^*$, we add a new element to the bottom of that order.

Comment: I see. Sorry I couldn't be of help.